# default function object value as function parameter to be called with a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, lambda

I want to have a method with a function object with default value as parameter, to be called with a lambda function, like for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void func(const std::function<void()>& f = {}){
  if(f) f();
  else std::cout << "or not" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  func([](){ std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; });
  func();
}
```

but on Visual Studio 2012 this does not compile (it compiles using Visual Studio 2015 or g++, for example), complaining about the default value {}. Change this to:

```
void func(const std::function<void()>& f = nullptr){
```

fix the problem. 
1) Is that a feature not supported by the compiler? 
2) Is there any difference between both?

Comment: It works on VS2015. For some definition of works. It compiles.

Comment: What does it means to have a default function?

Comment: 1) It compiles with `c++14` ([link](http://ideone.com/TiTiP9)). 2) If you want an *empty* labda you can write: `f = [](){}` - not just `f = {}`, but then you always get into `if`.

Comment: @NathanOliver The default state of the function wrapper is empty which means that it may not be invoked.

Comment: You have a method with *a function object* as a parameter, not a lambda. You can *call it* with lambdas because there exists an implicit constructor in std::function that takes one.

Comment: @Caleth I have rewritten a bit the question, I hope it is more specific now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is that a feature not supported by the compiler?

Your test appears to show that is the case. It is a standard feature, so not supporting it means that the compiler doesn't conform to the standard.

> 2) Is there any difference between both?

There is no difference. Both the default constructor and the constructor that takes `nullptr_t` behave exactly the same.